# Count certain letters in each document in a Quanteda corpus

Tags: r, data-science, quanteda

Specifically, I need to count the frequencies of each vowel in each document: *e* and *i* as "high" vowels; *a*, *o*, and *u* as "low" vowels.

Is there a way the count the frequencies of certain letters in each document in a quanteda corpus in R?
So far, I have only encountered functions that operate on word or sentence level, like `token_select()` or `ntoken()`.

Any help is welcome. I considered a regex pattern, but I'm not sure how to apply it to each individual document in a Quanteda corpus and get a count from it.

Here is a minimum working example to play around with:

```
require(quanteda)

text1 <- "This is some gibberish for you."
text2 <- "Some more gibberish. Enjoy!"
text3 <- "Gibber, gibber, gibber away."

corp <- rbind(text1, text2, text3) %>% 
  quanteda::corpus()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to tokenize the texts as characters, then use a dictionary mapping the vowels to two categories of high and low vowels.  Here's how:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.2

text1 <- "This is some gibberish for you."
text2 <- "Some more gibberish. Enjoy!"
text3 <- "Gibber, gibber, gibber away."

corp <- corpus(c(text1, text2, text3))

toks <- tokens(corp, what = "character")
dict <- dictionary(list(
  high_vowels = c("e", "i"),
  low_vowels = c("a", "o", "u")
))

tokens_lookup(toks, dict) %>%
  dfm()
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 2 features (0.0% sparse).
##        features
## docs    high_vowels low_vowels
##   text1           6          4
##   text2           6          3
##   text3           6          2
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Feel like I learnt a lot from your reply. I didn't understand before how powerful the dictionary() method is. A lot of use cases come to mind now. Thank you very much!